# Asp.Net MVC Unity dependency injection gives an exception when trying to resolve a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, dependency-injection, unity-container

My first time trying to implement a depency injection. I'm basing in other working projects of my company and web content at all.

I'm stuck in a case that the resolver tries to resolve a controller type. I did not registered any controller type(neither saw anything like that yet), so I'm confused.

Here is my registering at `Global.asax.cs`:

```
Container = new UnityContainer();
        
// repositories
foreach (var type in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UserRepository))
                    .GetTypes()
                    .Where(x => x.IsClass && x.Name.EndsWith("Repository")))
{
    Container.RegisterType(type);
}

// services
foreach (var type in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (TaskService))
                    .GetTypes()
                    .Where(x => x.IsClass && x.Name.EndsWith("Service")))
{
    Container.RegisterType(type);
}

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(Container));
```

Here is the `UnityDependencyResolver` method where the exception occurs:

```
private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
{
    this._container = container;
}

public object GetService(Type serviceType)
{
    if (!_container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
    {
        if (serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return _container.Resolve(serviceType); // Right on this line the exception occurs
}
```

This is the exception body([full text here](http://pastebin.com/uxMPuwBM)):

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Tasks.Controllers.TasksController", name = "(none)".
>
> Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>
> Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, NHibernate.ISessionFactory, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

As you can see, the problem happens when the resolver get the `TasksController` type to resolve (in `serviceType`) and crashes.

This is the relevant part of my controller(It is the only injection made yet in the project), if it helps:

```
protected TaskService TaskService { get; set; }

public TasksController(TaskService taskService)
{
    this.TaskService = taskService;
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: seems like the error says it all : You have to bind ISessionFactory to an implementation : for example, you may have a look at http://blog.pastelstudios.com/2013/09/16/asp-net-webapi-nhibernate-unity-application-architecture/

Answer (score 0):

There is a NuGet Package called "Unity bootstraper for ASP.NET MVC" targeted specifically for ASP.NET MVC web applications, have you tried this? Basically after installing it, just register what you want to inject into UnityConfig.cs under App_Start folder and you are good to go.

For example:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
    // container.LoadConfiguration();

    // TODO: Register your types here
    container.RegisterType<IAuthProvider, FormsAuthProvider>();
}
```

Where IAuthProvider is the interface and FormsAuthProvider is the actual implementation